# how to show entered data in the form when the form is submitted using php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to show the email in the email text input using this code but this code is not working when login is failed.

```
value= "if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ ?PHP echo $_POST[''email]?>";}
```

Comment: This is just a string literal containing text that almost looks like valid PHP code but isn't.  Where/how are you executing this code and what exactly are you expecting it to do?  At a glance it looks like what you want are just introductory tutorials to PHP...

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose PHP code in `<?php` and `?>`

Hence change:

```
   value= "if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ ?PHP echo $_POST[''email];"}
```

to

```
   value= "<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { echo $_POST["email"]; } ?>"
```

Comment: Worth noting normally you would escape the echo string  to prevent XSS vulnerability